# Running a script that reads /etc/shadow without having to log in as root

Tags: shell, command-line, syntax

I am currently in a situation that requires a command that you can normally run as a root user to be run by a non root user.

The command is as follows.

```
UserAccs=`awk -F: '$1 !~ /^[[:space:]]*#/ && $3>=500 && $3!=65534 {print $1}' /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null`
for Acc in $UserAccs; do
    awk -F: '$1 ~ /^[[:space:]]*'$Acc'$/ && $2!~/[!*]+/ {print Acc":PASS_MIN_DAYS="$4, "PASS_MAX_DAYS="$5, "PASS_WARN_AGE="$6, "INACTIVE="$7}' Acc=$Acc /etc/shadow 2>/dev/null
done
```

The expected result should be this:

```
Novatech:PASS_MIN_DAYS=0 PASS_MAX_DAYS=99999 PASS_WARN_AGE=7 INACTIVE=
```

However as a non root user I get nothing:

```
$ UserAccs=`awk -F: '$1 !~ /^[[:space:]]*#/ && $3>=500 && $3!=65534 {print $1}' /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null`
$ for Acc in $UserAccs; do
>     awk -F: '$1 ~ /^[[:space:]]*'$Acc'$/ && $2!~/[!*]+/ {print Acc":PASS_MIN_DAYS="$4, "PASS_MAX_DAYS="$5, "PASS_WARN_AGE="$6, "INACTIVE="$7}' Acc=$Acc /etc/shadow 2>/dev/null
> done
$
```

However if I go into su mode I can run the command again.

So the question is 2 fold:

1. Is there a way that I can run the above command as a non - root user format in embedded Linux?
2. If so - is there a better way to do this? If not then is entering the su command required in order to run the command?

Embedded Linux version used: 4.4.36-rt43-yocto-preempt-rt

Comment: Protip: `2> /dev/null` means "don't give me any helpful tips or diagnostics". Consider waiting until you're entirely done with the script and testing before you add it (and only if you really, really have to)

Comment: BTW, substituting `$Acc` into your awk script is dangerous -- use `awk -v var="$value"` to create an awk variable from a shell variable in a way that doesn't enable injection attacks.

Comment: Also, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). And consider using `getent` instead of reading `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` directly -- that'll enable your script to work with systems using LDAP/ActiveDirectory/NIS/other miscellaneous directory services (so long as they implement the relevant interface).

Comment: Anyhow, moving towards the topic -- does your particular embedded Linux distro have a `sudo` command? If so, you can configure `/etc/sudoers` to allow your particular script to be invoked without a password. (You don't want to enable that globally, or for all `sudo cat /etc/shadow` invocations, since that would defeat the whole point of `/etc/shadow` being readable only by root).

Comment: BTW, why does your script try to handle leading whitespace in `/etc/shadow`? There should never be leading whitespace in that file.

Answer (score 1):

The easy thing is to write a wrapper in C: Once that's compiled, you can set the setuid bit to cause it to be run as root.

---

#### Embedding A Shell Script In A C String

To convert your shell script into a C literal, one can do the following:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
script=$(cat <<'EOF'
while read -r Acc; do
    awk -v Acc="$Acc" -F: '$1 = Acc && $2!~/[!*]+/ {print Acc":PASS_MIN_DAYS="$4, "PASS_MAX_DAYS="$5, "PASS_WARN_AGE="$6, "INACTIVE="$7}' Acc=$Acc /etc/shadow
done < <(awk -F: '$1 !~ /^[[:space:]]*#/ && $3>=500 && $3!=65534 {print $1}' /etc/passwd)
EOF
)
script_c=$script
script_c=${script_c//$'\\'/'\\'}
script_c=${script_c//$'\n'/'\n'}
script_c=${script_c//$'\"'/'\"'}
printf '"%s"\n' "$script_c"
```

...which will generate the following as output:

```c
"while read -r Acc; do\n    awk -v Acc=\"$Acc\" -F: '$1 = Acc && $2!~/[!*]+/ {print Acc\":PASS_MIN_DAYS=\"$4, \"PASS_MAX_DAYS=\"$5, \"PASS_WARN_AGE=\"$6, \"INACTIVE=\"$7}' Acc=$Acc /etc/shadow\ndone < <(awk -F: '$1 !~ /^[[:space:]]*#/ && $3>=500 && $3!=65534 {print $1}' /etc/passwd)"
```

---

#### Writing a Shim In C Invoking That Script

So, let's use that to build a C program:

```c
/* the below assumes this is saved as check_password_expirations.c */
#include <unistd.h>

const char *interpreter = "/bin/bash";
const char *script_argv[] = { "/bash", "-c", "while read -r Acc; do\n    awk -v Acc=\"$Acc\" -F: '$1 = Acc && $2!~/[!*]+/ {print Acc\":PASS_MIN_DAYS=\"$4, \"PASS_MAX_DAYS=\"$5, \"PASS_WARN_AGE=\"$6, \"INACTIVE=\"$7}' Acc=$Acc /etc/shadow\ndone < <(awk -F: '$1 !~ /^[[:space:]]*#/ && $3>=500 && $3!=65534 {print $1}' /etc/passwd)", NULL };
const char *minimal_env[] = { "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin", NULL };

int main(void) {
  execve(interpreter, script_argv, minimal_env);
  return 1; /* if this is reached, we failed. */
}
```

---

#### Installation

To make sure that C program runs with root privileges *every time it's invoked*, you can chown it to root and enable the setuid bit.

In the below transcript, `dev` is expected to be the workstation where you installed the Yocto Application Development Toolkit, and `emb` is expected to be your embedded system.

```
user@dev$ arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o check-password-expirations check_password_expirations.c
user@dev$ scp check-password-expirations your-embedded-host:
user@dev$ ssh user@your-embedded-host
user@emb$ su -
root@emb# mv ~user/check-password-expirations /usr/local/bin
root@emb# chown root:root /usr/local/bin/check-password-expirations
root@emb# chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/check-password-expirations
```

Thereafter, `check-password-expirations` will itself always run as root when invoked from `/usr/local/bin` on `emb`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to give a non-root user access to `/etc/shadow`.
When you do require such information regularly, and have consent of your administrator, you might consider a root cron job that will expose the data you need (not the encrypted password) to another file that can only be read by users in some special group.

Comment: Giving the world read access to `/etc/passwd` (not `/etc/shadow`) is completely standard -- that's **why** `/etc/shadow` exists at all, to store data (like password hashes) it isn't safe to make publicly available in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: ...but, yeah, since they need `/etc/shadow` too, it's a problem.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking shadow when I wrote `/etc/passwd`. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you need to do periodically then run out of root's crontab. If it's something you or an admin need to do more than once or twice then put it in a script then run `sudo script`. If it's a one off, then, the problem is that `/etc/shadow` needs to *not* be world readable. In the loop, change `awk ...` to `sudo awk...`, or, better, `sudo cat /etc/shadow | awk ...`.

Comment: Enabling passwordless `sudo cat /etc/shadow` is a pretty big security hole, vs allowing passwordless sudo of a script that summarizes non-password fields but leaves out the most sensitive content. If you want to minimize the damage an attacker (who's gained access to a nonprivileged account) can do, I know which one I'd prefer.

Comment: Really? "passwordless" sudo is how most distro's come from the factory:

    # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
    %sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Comment: Sure, but that means you're trusting everyone in the `sudo` group to secure their account. It's not a privilege to grant to anyone you wouldn't give complete root access.

Comment: And, you've got it all backwards. A script `#! ...` is the security hole, not `sudo cat`.

Comment: Eh? If the script is owned by root, only root (who only controls `/etc/sudoers`) can edit it. If you do something idiotic like giving an untrusted user write access to a `sudo`able-script, sure, but... that's idiotic.

Comment: Right, that's how sudo works. You give trust to someone that you trust. If you don't trust them then you don't give trust.

Comment: `/etc/sudoers` allows a fine-grained whitelist of specific commands, with restrictions on their arguments, environment variables, and other execution context. Just because people are often too lazy to use the tool the way it's designed doesn't mean it isn't designed to be used that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174532/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-keithpjolley).